# How to iterate JSON data and add individual CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am using JSON data to show each article title and cover image on a HTML page using the code below, but when I try to add CSS commands to the div tags to add some margins and other styling, they are not actioned. Looking into the console, the title and image div's are not labelled with the id's and classes I specified in the HTML (see image below).

[image]

Is anybody able to identify what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <img src="images/cn-header.jpg" alt="logo" />
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="one_article">
    <div class="title-home"></div>
    <div class="cover-home"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<div>';
      article_data += '<div>' + value.title + '</div>';
      article_data += '<div> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';  
      article_data += '</div>';
    });
    $('#one_article').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 10px 100px 10px;
}
#header img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
#one_article {

}
.title-home {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.cover-home {

}
.cover-home img {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding classes to the divs, (and it's better to use a class for the articles, and append to the container not to the article) use this :

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<div class="article">';
      article_data += '<div class="title-home">' + value.title + '</div>';
      article_data += '<div class="cover-home"> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';  
      article_data += '</div>';
    });
$('#container').append(article_data);
```

```
.article {
    /*CSS-CODE for all articles*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you append `article_data` to your element in the DOM, they are added right after the existing elements inside `#one_article` element (`<div class="title-home"></div>` and `<div class="cover-home"></div>`). So it has nothing to do with the elements you generate in Javascript. What you need to do is to change

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  article_data += '<div>';
  article_data += '<div>' + value.title + '</div>';
  article_data += '<div> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';  
  article_data += '</div>';
});
```

INTO

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  article_data += '<div>';
  article_data += '<div class="title-home">' + value.title + '</div>';
  article_data += '<div class="cover-home"> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';  
  article_data += '</div>';
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation and solution. Thank you very much! It works perfectly.